# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter не обновляет позицию в списке

Tags: java, recyclerview, firebase, список

Создал адаптер для Firebase+RecyclerView. в нем TextView и Button удалить.

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String,TaskViewHolder>  adapter  = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, TaskViewHolder>(
            String.class,
            R.layout.task_conteiner,
            TaskViewHolder.class,
            myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("Tasks")
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(TaskViewHolder viewHolder, String model, final int position) {
        viewHolder.thisTask.setText(model);
        viewHolder.buttonDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseReference itemRef = getRef(position);
                itemRef.removeValue();
            }
        });
        }
    };
    rvTasks.setAdapter(adapter); //присвоил Адаптер списку.
```

В итоге удаление не меняет позицию на кнопке. Когда я удаляю вторую позицию списка, остальной список подтягивается вышел. И если я удаляю опять вторую позицию (которая до этого была третей) то удаляется вместо этой позиции третья(которая в свою очередь изначально была четвертой). 
Как исправить?

В классе extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder. 2 ссылки, текстовое поле и кнопка.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно вот.
viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()﻿ нужно в позиции указать. нашел